# Discrete Mathematics Proofs for ∃ and ∀

Tags: discrete-mathematics, predicate-logic

Premises or Givens:

- $∃x(A(x) → B(x))$
- $∀x (B(x) → K(x))$

To Prove:

- $∃x(A(x) → K(x))$

My Solution:

1. $A(z) → B(z)$  From premise and  Existential instantiation $x$ for $z$
2. $B(z) → K(z)$  From premise and  Universal instantiation $x$ for $z$
3. $A(z) → K(z)$  Transitivity of 1,2
4. $∃x(A(x) → K(x))$  From Existential generalization (Substitute $z$ for $x$)

OR

I was thinking about assuming $A(z)$ and then using Modus Ponens to get $B(z)$ and then further $K(z)$, then using the deduction theorem on $A(z)$ and $K(z)$, and then using Existential Generalization on that statement by substituting $x$ for $z$.

> Can someone suggest which way would be more effective?
>
> Is there any other effective way to solve it?

Comment: You gave the solution. There really is no other one in such a simple case.

Comment: This seems like a math question, so off-topic here.

Comment: Welcome to Computer Science! The title you have chosen is not well suited to representing your question. Please take some time to improve it; we have collected some advice [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/a/815/). Thank you!

Comment: We discourage "please check whether my answer is correct" questions, as only "yes/no" answers are possible, which won't help you or future visitors. See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/597/) and [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/519/). Can you edit your post to ask about a specific conceptual issue you're uncertain about? As a rule of thumb, a good conceptual question should be useful even to someone who isn't looking at the problem you happen to be working on. If you just need someone to check your work, you might seek out a friend, classmate, or teacher.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus We usually treat logics questions as ontopic, why not this one?

Comment: @Raphael It might depend on the nature of the question, and different community standards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution is a good one, and that's how I'd prove it also. I don't believe a more straightforward or simpler version is possible.